# PHP - How to get the permissions of a file in Unix system

Tags: php, file-permissions, chmod

I need to get the permission of a file in Unix system in PHP. I tried `stat()` and `fileperms()` methods but both returns something like `33188`,`16877`. But I am expecting the permission values like `755`,`777` etc.

Comment: If you read the [PHP Docs for fileperms()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php), then example #2 shows how to get the result as rwx..... the PHP Docs are there to help you, learn to read them

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker I really missed it..

Comment: Tip: `var_dump( base_convert('33188', 10, 8) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`fileperms()`](http://php.net/fileperms) function here:

```
clearstatcache();
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('demo')), -4);//0775
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('phptest/PHP_test')), -4);//0775
```

As suggested by [Ravi Hirani's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35938534/2667307) answer you may use
[`is_readable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php), [`is_executable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php) etc. commands.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [*Mark Baker in his comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker), and [*Shashank Shah's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35938031/4198099), you can use [`fileperms()`](http://php.net/fileperms) function to get file permission as below:

```
function getFilePermission($file) {
      $length = strlen(decoct(fileperms($file)))-3;
      return substr(decoct(fileperms($file)),$length); // "777" ,"755" for example 
}
```

There is another alternative also. You can also check whether file

- [`is_readable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)
- [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)
- [`is_executable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php)

Hope it will also help you :-)